# Office 2016 installing different build numbers on different PC's from same install file

Tags: csv, installation, ms-office, excel-2016, office-2016

I'm at a loss.  When I install Office 2016 (we use a volume license) depending on the machine, I get build #16.04XXXX and some machines I get build #16.05XXXX.  both copies work fine, but in #16.04XX my macros are incompatible.  I've tried all the fixes I've come across and no luck.  Any ideas????

[error message when refreshing data] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/QShcK.png)

Uninstall and reinstalled program, edited registry files, and changed macro connection settings.

Answer (score 1):

Well I got it to work by adjusting the Macro syntax in build 16.04XXX  removing the Column parameter and the QuoteStyle parameter fixed the issue.